# Covariant or contravariant nature of Gradient

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, vectors, covariance

I've been having this confusion regarding the **gradient** being a **covariant** vector. Intuitively I seem to have understood the concept. However, mathematically, I'm unable to show this, in a single example.

Let us have our normal cartesian coordinates at the beginning. I don't know what exactly is the '**gradient**', is it just the **operator**, or is it the **operator acting on a scalar** ? So, I'm considering both cases here.

The gradient operator (taking only x axis into consideration) here is supposed to be
$ \nabla_x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$

Let us suppose, we scaled the x-coordinate, with a scalar $a$. In our new coordinate system, let us call this new axis $u$, with the relation $u=ax$.

In this new coordinate, the gradient operator should be $ \nabla_u = \frac{\partial}{\partial u} $

If I try to relate the two operators, I get :

**$ \nabla_u = \frac{\partial}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial}{(a)\partial x} = \frac{\nabla_x}{a}$**

What I see here, is that the gradient operator is behaving exactly opposite to our change of coordinates. If the **coordinates** are scaled **up** by $a$, the **operator** is getting scaled **down** by $a$
The operator seems to act '**contravariantly to our coordinate change**'

However, this is resolved, if I consider the Gradient to be $ \nabla_x (f(x))$
Under the same coordinate scaling, our function would become $f(ax)=f(u)$. Let us see the gradient on this :

$\nabla_x f(ax) = \frac{\partial f(ax)}{\partial x} = a \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}$

Since $u$ is a dummy variable, we can probably write $\nabla_u = a \nabla_x$

However, if we had defined the gradient in this case, to be $ \nabla_u f(u) =\frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u} $, then we reach the first conundrum again. The gradient seems to scale opposite to the coordinate.

My first question is, how is the gradient defined if we scale the x-axis :

Is it $ \nabla_x f(ax) = \frac{\partial f(ax)}{\partial x}$  ? Or is it $\nabla_u f(u) = \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}$ , where $ u=ax$ ?

So, in these cases, the gradient does seem to act 'covariantly to the change of coordinates'. However, I might have made some mistakes, but can someone point it out to me, with this particular example where the x-axis is scaled in the new coordinate system. Can someone also tell me how exactly is the gradient defined in this case ? Instead of using the general transformation rules, can someone show me with this example, of scaling the x axis, that the gradient is co-variant ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a scalar function $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$, where $M$ is some smooth manifold.  You can restrict your attention to $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$ if you only want to talk about elementary vector calculus, but in fact I find these cases to be almost complicated by their simplicity.

There are two distinct objects which are commonly called the gradient of $f$.

1. The one-form (or *covector*) field $\mathrm df$, which eats a vector field $X$ and spits out $\mathrm df(X) := X(f)$
2. The vector field $\nabla f$, which is dual to $\mathrm df$ under the duality provided by the metric tensor $g$. Explicitly, in component form we have that $(\nabla f)^\mu = g^{\mu\nu} (\mathrm df)_\nu$.

---

In any coordinates $\{\xi^\mu\}$, the components of $\mathrm df$ are given by $(\mathrm df)_\mu^{(\xi)} = \partial f/\partial \xi^\mu$.  If we change coordinates from $\{\xi^\mu\}$ to $\{x^\mu\}$, then the components of the gradient change accordingly:
$$\left(\mathrm df\right)_\mu^{(x)} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\mu} = \frac{\partial \xi^\nu}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi^\nu} = \frac{\partial \xi^\nu}{\partial x^\mu}(\mathrm df)_\nu^{(\xi)}$$
If, as in your example, $x=a\xi$, then $\frac{\partial \xi^\nu}{\partial x^\mu} = \frac{1}{a}\delta^\nu_\mu$ and so $(\mathrm df)_\mu^{(x)} = \frac{1}{a}(\mathrm df)_\mu^{(\xi)}$.

---

On the other hand, the components of $\nabla f$ are obtained from the aforementioned components of $\mathrm df$ via contraction with the (inverse) metric tensor, which means that in coordinates $\{\xi^\mu\}$, the components of $\nabla f$ are given by
$$(\nabla f)^\mu_{(\xi)} = g^{\mu\nu}_{(\xi)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi^\nu}$$
where $g^{\mu\nu}_{(\xi)}$ are the components of $g$ in the same coordinates. Under change of coordinates, we use the chain rule as before **as well as** the transformation rules for the metric components;  the result in general is

$$(\nabla f)^\mu_{(x)} = g^{\mu\nu}_{(x)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\nu} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \xi^a} \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial \xi^b}g^{ab}_{(\xi)}}_{g^{\mu\nu}_{(x)}}\underbrace{ \frac{\partial \xi^c}{\partial x^\nu} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi^c}}_{\partial f/\partial x^\nu}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \xi^a} g^{ab}_{(\xi)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi^b}$$
$$= \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \xi^\nu} (\nabla f)^\nu_{(\xi)}$$

In your case, we would have
$$(\nabla f)^\mu_{(x)} = a (\nabla f)^\mu_{(\xi)}$$

---

> I don't know what exactly is the 'gradient', is it just the operator, or is it the operator acting on a scalar ? So, I'm considering both cases here.

The objects $\mathrm df$ and $\nabla f$ are both commonly referred to as the gradient **of the function** $f$.  The components of $\mathrm df$ transform covariantly (with respect to the basis, see below) while the components of $\nabla f$ transform contravariantly.  It is common in certain contexts to abstract this to the gradient *operator*, which eats a function $f$ and returns one of the two objects described above.

> The operator seems to act 'contravariantly to our coordinate change'

The terms *contravariant* and *covariant* are used to refer to how the components change relative to how the **basis** changes, not the coordinates.  In coordinates $\{\xi^\mu\}$, the coordinate-induced basis is given by $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi^\mu}\}$.  Therefore, the operator you describe transforms **co**variantly because it transforms in the same way as the corresponding basis.

> However, this is resolved, if I consider the Gradient to be $\nabla_x f(x) $($\ldots$)

This part of your reasoning doesn't make sense - you can't scale the argument of $f$ without also scaling the coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial y^\nu}\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x^\mu} = \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y^\nu}
$$
is the change of coordinate transformation for the compoents of a covariant vector:
$$
\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial y^\nu} V_\mu = V'_\nu, \quad V_\mu = \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x^\mu}
$$